# While making Plot in pandas python I am getting Error: EOL

Tags: python, pandas, plot

df

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'SKU': ['BIKES','MATS', 'BLANKETS', 'CREAMS'],'Col1': [1,3,6,10],'Col2': [4,5, 6,16],'Month':[1,2,3,4],'Year':['2015','2010','2011','2012']})
```

Code tried which doesnt work

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Visualisations

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for col in ['Col1', 'Col2']:
    ax.plot(df[col], label=col)
ax.legend(loc="best")
ax.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=30)
```

I need tickers for months and values for years. But before I can proceed with tickers etc., I am getting error:

```
File "<ipython-input-14-136f7818ccc7>", line 6
    for col in ['Col1', 'Col2']:
                                ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: you have wrong quotation marks in this line:  `" ’  ‘ ’` - you need `" "` or `' '`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are getting error because you have not given dates in the for loop. For which dates do you need the plot?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates as mdates

# The new column to be used as x axis
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month']].assign(Day=1))

# Plot the data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 2))
for col in ['Col1', 'Col2']:
    ax.plot(df['Date'], df[col], label=col)  #Note I have inserted df['Date'] before df[col] in the code
ax.legend(loc="best")
ax.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=30)
```

**Adding tickers as required by you in the second edit:**

```
years = mdates.YearLocator()    # only print label for the years
months = mdates.MonthLocator()  # mark months as ticks
years_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y')

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(years_fmt)

ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are opening a specific type of apostrophes and never closing it:

<strike>for col in ["Col1’, ‘Col2’]:</strike>

Needs to be replaced with:

```
for col in ["Col1","Col2"]:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for col in ['Col1', 'Col2']:
    ax.plot(df['Date'], df[col], label=col)
```